# facebook oauthtoken in django session

Tags: django, facebook, oauth, facebook-oauth, django-socialauth

Is it possible for me to store the `oauth` token directly into the session when a user logs into my website using fblogin

Iam using `django-social-auth` and it stores `_auth_user_id` into the session and i dont want to query the user model to get the oauth token saved in database.

Comment: Why not? What are you trying to do?